# The VSCode does not work after adding numpy module

Tags: python, numpy, module

```
import numpy as np 

print(dir(np))
```

and the VSCode has no response ... in addition to I installed the numpy and the terminal of vscode says to me (Successfully installed numpy-1.25.2) but when I import the module no response in any code even if `print(7+4)` and I didn't find any solution.

Comment: How are you running the file? How did you install `numpy`. Are you using a virtual environment? Please provide some more details. Thanks you!

Comment: I'm using Visual studio code and running the file by the vsc compiler (clicking run on run button in VSCode)

Comment: Got it. How did you install `numpy`?

Comment: Could it be that you are running a different file? Since even `print(7+4)` doesn't print...

Comment: Joshua Shew ... I installed numpy by the pip >> pip install numpy ... and the result was Successfully installed numpy-1.25.2

Comment: doneforaiur ... nope I'm sure it's the correct file because i tried different files and same result